# bpy.types.Scene.customVar not reset

Tags: python, scripting, scene

First, excuse me for my poor english... I'm french ! I'm going to try you do understand me.

I'm writting a script with python for Blender. And I need to store variables. So, I store my variables like this :

```
bpy.types.Scene.myCustomVar = bpy.props.StringProperty()
bpy.types.Scene.myCustomVar = "OK"
```

That's OK ! I can read or edit my variable. But, when I edit my variable, and open another file (or a new file), my variable isn't reset. But me, I need that variable to be empty when you start a scene.

How do I that ?

Thank you very much (and excuse me AGAIN for my english)

Comment: First line of code in question defines a property on the scene class (all good) the second really should be setting an instance `bpy.context.scene.foo = "OK"` , which if that value is not default is stored in blend file as `bpy.context.scene["foo"]`

Comment: `bpy.context.*` is read only. So, we can't change like that. We can change `bpy.types.Scene.foo`, but if I open another file, `bpy.context.scene.foo` isn't reset.

Comment: Trust me monkey patching _eg_ , `bpy.types.Scene.myCustomVar = "OK"` isn't the way to go and is adding confusion to what it is you are asking. This `bpy.types.Scene.myCustomVar = bpy.props.StringProperty()` sets up a property on the instance of a scene, _eg_ `bpy.context.scene.myCustomVar` or `bpy.data.scenes["BFF"].myCustomVar`  When a new file is opened, while the property def is loaded a new scene will be given the properties default. Why is `bpy.context` being read only an issue?

Comment: I'm sorry. I saw badly. I did `bpy.context.scene.foo = "foo"` and not `bpy.context.scene['foo'] = "foo"`. Now it's working ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Still confused, if  you define `Scene.foo = StringProperty(default="Bar")` then either of above will work.  `scene["foo"]` is how it is stored in blend file as an ID property, when set to non default (_eg_ "Bar" )

Comment: I'm confused, I don't understand. If I want create a "global" variable, I have to use `bpy.type.Scene.foo = bpy.props.StringProperty()` (with a default value if I want). After that, if I want set a value, I call `bpy.context.scene['foo'] = "value"`. I've everything good ?